# Inter-scale correlation matrix wide format to long format (in R)

Tags: r, matrix, correlation, reshape2

In one of my datafiles, correlation matrices are stored in long format, where the first three columns represent the variables and the last three columns represent the inter-scale correlations. Frustratingly, I have to admit, the rows may represent different sub-dimensions of particular construct (e.g., the 0s in column 1).

The datafile (which is used for a meta-analysis) was constructed by a PhD-student who "decomposed" all relevant correlation matrices by hand (so the wide- format matrix was not generated by another piece of code).

**Example**

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]
[1,]    0    4    1 -0.32  0.25 -0.08
[2,]    0    4    2 -0.32  0.15 -0.04
[3,]    0    4    3 -0.32 -0.04  0.27
[4,]    0    4    4 -0.32 -0.14 -0.16
[5,]    0    4    1 -0.01  0.33 -0.08
[6,]    0    4    2 -0.01  0.36 -0.04
[7,]    0    4    3 -0.01  0.04  0.27
[8,]    0    4    4 -0.01 -0.03 -0.16
```

My question is, how to restore the interscale-correlation matrix. Such that,

```
    c1_0a   c1_0b   c2_4    c3_1    c3_2    c3_3    c3_4
c1_0a                           
c1_0b                           
c2_4    -0.32   -0.01                   
c3_1    0.25    0.33    -0.08               
c3_2    0.15    0.36    -0.04               
c3_3    -0.04   0.04    0.27                
c3_4    -0.14   -0.03   -0.16
```

I suppose this can be done with the reshape2 package, but I am unsure how to proceed. Your help is greatly appreciated!

What I have tried so far (rather clumpsy):

1. I identified the unique combinations of column 1,2, and 4 which I transposed to correlation matrix #1;
2. Similarily, I identified the unique combinations of column 1,3, and 5 which I transposed to correlation matrix #2;
3. Similarily, I identified the unique combinations of column 2,3, and 6 which I transposed to correlation matrix #3;
4. Next, I binded the three matrices which gives the incorrect solution.

The problem here is that matrix #1 has different dimensions [as there are two different correlations reported for the relationship between the first construct (0) and the second construct (4)] than matrix #3 [as there are eight different correlations reported for the second construct (4) and the third construct (1-4)].

I tried both the `melt`and `reshape2`packages to overcome these problems (and to come up with a more elegant solution), but I did not find any clues about how to set up functions in these packages to reconstruct the correlation matrix.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you edit the relevant portions code you have (that doesn't work) into your question?

Comment: Please show how you generate the matrix. That really matters not just output.

Comment: yes, what did you try so far. Have you worked with melt?

Comment: I added your requested information to my question. Is it sufficiently clear now? Thanks!